# Fast highlighting in android EditText

Tags: android, performance, android-edittext, syntax-highlighting

I'm working on IDE and now highlighting the source code using EditText takes about ~21 seconds for few thousands of tokens (regular source file). Is there any opportunity to speed it up?

```
public boolean doHighlight(List<HighlightToken> tokens) {
        log("doHighlight(tokens)");

        Editable text = getText();
        String textString = text.toString();

        try {
            for (HighlightToken eachToken: tokens) {
                text.setSpan(
                    new ForegroundColorSpan(highlighter.getColor(eachToken, theme, textString)),
                    eachToken.getStart(),
                    eachToken.getEnd(),
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
            return true;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            log(t.getMessage());
            return false;
        } finally {
            log("doHighlight(tokens) finished");
        }
    }
```

> 01-04 15:06:28.949: ERROR/CodeEdit(6519): doHighlight(tokens)
>
> 01-04 15:06:49.371: ERROR/CodeEdit(6519): doHighlight(tokens) finished

Update: I've found http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#beginBatchEdit() but it seems to be useless

Update2: One can't use background thread as only UI thread can be used to touch widgets, so standard approach with background workers does not work.

Comment: Do you test it on an emulator or on a real device?

Comment: real device - Snapdragon 600, 2Gb RAM

Answer (score 0):

The only approach i've found working is to highlight only visible EditText area instead of all  the document and rehighlight when scrolled